# How to create message shortcut in slack app?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

I am creating slack app using bolt javascript library, I want to create message shortcut and when the user clicks on that shortcut I want to capture the message details. how can I do that using slack's blot library for javascript?

like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in a [Slack API docs on shortcuts](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts). You should go to https://api.slack.com/apps, pick your app and open application admin, choose Features -> Interactivity & Shortcuts, enable this feature, then "Create New Shortcut" in Shortcuts section.

There are basically two options for shortcuts: global and on message, pick message, Callback ID is an action identifier where application should filter your action.

You should add a shortcut listener in your application, if you are using Slack BoltJS framework, see the [Listening and responding to shortcuts](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#shortcuts), use the "Callback ID" as an identifier for your application shortcut business logic.

You probably also enable a socket mode for your app or set an interactivity endpoint in a "Request URL" form, see the [Sending and responding to actions](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started#sending-and-responding-to-actions).

Comment: Seems that this option no longer works in the [Next generation Slack platform](https://api.slack.com/automation/quickstart) app development experience. Link triggers seem to be limited to bookmarks, global shortcuts and workflow buttons.